# File writing error

Tags: php, file

I'm using this code to log file downloads:

```
define('LOG_DOWNLOADS',true);
define('LOG_FILE','logs/downloads.log');

// log downloads
if (!LOG_DOWNLOADS) die();

$f = fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a+');
if ($f) {
  fputs($f, date("m.d.Y g:ia")."  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."  ".$fname."\r\n");
  fclose($f);
}
```

Code works perfectly in local outputting a log file like:

```
08.21.2012 6:31pm  127.0.0.1  1.test1.mp3
08.21.2012 6:32pm  127.0.0.1  1.test2.mp3
```

But doesn't work on my domain hosted at Godaddy? Now idea why, maybe file permissions?

Comment: It can be related to your PHP configuration (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Comment: Thanks, but tried ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1); and doesn't work either. Plus I have used fopen in other scritps and worked fine at the server.

Comment: You're suppressing potential error messages. How do you expect the script to tell you what's wrong?

Comment: @MetalFrog, thanks, took advice, but outputs no errors without @ symbols

Comment: @qalbiol Make sure your file is CHMOD `0755` or higher.

Comment: Thanks MetalFrog, still not working, don't know what else I can try!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- First of all, remove all the `@` symbols, so that you can find out exactly what error message you get
- check if `logs/downloads.log` exists and if it does what is the permission assigned to it? It would also be advisable to give full path to `logs/downloads.log`

Can you try this script? I just added more condition checks to see if we can track where it is causing issues:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('LOG_DOWNLOADS',true);
define('LOG_FILE','downloads.log');

// log downloads
if (!LOG_DOWNLOADS) die("Not logging downloads");

$f = fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a+');
if ($f) {
  if(!fputs($f, date("m.d.Y g:ia")."  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."  ".$fname."\r\n"))
  {
    die("Could not write into file ". LOG_FILE);
  }
  if(!fclose($f))
  {
    die("Could not fclose file ". LOG_FILE);
  }
}
else
{
    die("Could not fopen file ". LOG_FILE);
}

die("Finished logging..");
?>
```

Comment: Hi, without @ symbols, it outputs no errors, download works fine, but doesn't log. Log exists or not, does not work either way, tried giving all privileges to that file... Now has 0604 (Read / Write). Thanks!

Comment: `if (!LOG_DOWNLOADS) die();` - can you add some message like `die("Not logging downloads..");` just to make sure that is not where the program is cutting off?

Comment: Added message, no errors... I don't know whatelse to do... Tried changing file permissions to 0755, dir permissions, nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm..I have updated my answer with a modified version of your script - can you try run that and see if it helps track what is happening?

Comment: Tried the script, no apparent errors... downloads.log exists and has 0755 permissions. I'm retrieving the file from link like http://www.domain.com/download.php?f=test1.mp3. I found a rare thing, if I delete logs folder (which holds downloads.log), gives no error at all? Additionally with your script, it logs twice. Thanks again!

Comment: It wont give error if you delete the log, because you are `fopen`-ing it with `a+` which means that it will create the file if it does not exist. Actually the script is not logging twice - you ran the file twice it seems. You see `a+` means write into file in `append mode`, so every time you run the script it will keep *appending* into `download.log`

Comment: Tried again, it just writes once, no idea what I did, but still no error or correct working xD

Comment: When you say *no error or correct working*, what do you mean? what is not working correctly?

Comment: I mean it is still not writing the file. Still works perfectly while on my local server, but not on my hosting :S

Comment: Two final things I can think of is: (1) download.php has some issues and is downloading a blank file perhaps (2) If everything in local is fine, it might as well be time to contact your hosting service - maybe something is different in their settings(?)

Comment: Yes, I think contacting my hosting will be the best solution! Thanks for your time anyway!